# Generate regular expression based on inputted number

Tags: php, regex

This is my first PHP script (although I like to think I'm a good general coder).

The script accepts a number from the user, uses it to generate a regular expression, and then returns all dictionary words that match that expression.

It's currently live [here](http://www.joereddington.com/major/majorEncoder.php), and I'd appreciate any comments on style, security, best practices, and even efficiency. Please ignore the Html for now - it's got a WordPress template to be inserted into later on.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Major Analysis Number Encoder</title>
</head>
<body>
    <H1>Tool for finding keywords for major analysis</h1>
    This tool uses the numbering system shown by Derren Brown in the
    excellent book
    <a
        href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/Tricks-Mind-Derren-Brown/dp/1905026269">Trick
        of the mind</a>. For a (much better) tool that uses the older
    numbering system see
    <a href="http://www.rememberg.com/">http://www.rememberg.com/</a><br>
    <form action="majorEncoder.php" method="post">
        <label for="firstname">Number to encode (at least three digits
            please):</label> <input type="text" id="targetNumber"
            name="targetNumber" /><br /> <input type="submit"
            value="Generate results" name="submit" />
    </form>
<?php
if ($_POST != null) {

    $target = $_POST ['targetNumber'];
    if (strlen ( $target ) >= 3) {
        $f = '[waeiouyc]?';
        $regex = '/^' . $f . $target;
        echo 'You entered the target' . $target . '<br><br>';
        $regex = str_replace ( '1', 'l' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '2', 'n' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '3', 'm' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '4', 'r' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '5', '[fv]' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '6', '[bp]' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '7', 't' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '8', '[sc]h' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '9', '[gd]' . $f, $regex );
        $regex = str_replace ( '0', '[sz]' . $f, $regex );
        $lines = file ( 'words.txt' );

        $fl_array = preg_grep ( $regex . '$/', $lines );
        if (sizeof ( $fl_array ) > 0) {
            echo 'Exact matches: <br>';
            foreach ( $fl_array as $element ) {
                echo $element . '<br>';
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }
        $fl_array = preg_grep ( $regex . '/', $lines );
        if (sizeof ( $fl_array ) > 0) {
            echo 'Matches that allow trailing characters: <br>';
            foreach ( $fl_array as $element ) {
                echo $element . '<br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo "No matches found for the input $target";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter at least three digits<br>';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would do is that `str_replace` can receive an array of items to look for and an array of its replacement:

[PHP str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
// Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

instead of going line by line to do it.

Just nit-picking but

sizeof() is an alias of count() and count() is more widely used, so use something that is more general in the PHP community

Also $_POST != null would typically be !isset($_POST) rather as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949066/if-post-is-empty-function)